# Laravel showing deleted files also

Tags: php, laravel

I have created a simple upload form which resizes, encode to jpg (with help of intervention) and uploads the image to the directory public/profilepics/user['id']/profile.jpg.

Next I created a simple function delete to delete the picture from above mentioned directory.

The upload form also show the current profile.jpg in the respective folder. But when I have successfully deleted the picture(I confirmed by looking into the public/profilepics directory in file browser), I still see the old picture. After uploading another image, again I see the old image only.

Do laravel have remembering capability or have internal cache(I am not talking about the cache service include in laravel [This one](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache)) which should be cleared to see the new image.

Actually I was working on updating profile picture page and encountered this problem.

Leave the comment if any of the file is needed.

Comment: I think it would be useful to see the HTTP request that is generated when you expect to not see the image, and possibly the logic in the backend that delivers it.

Comment: For this purpose I used simple php and html(no blade) but I don't find any errors and How is it possible for laravel to show a file that doesn't exist

Comment: Are you sure that Larvel is displaying the right folder and not PHP's temporary folder or something like that?

Comment: Yes I have set it to display the images from a folder in public folder "OF LARAVEL"